# Why is automapper making Entity Framework insert instead of update?

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, poco

I have a Customers table with a foreign reference to the Addresses table.  It appears that AutoMapper is doing something to make EF think that my Address reference is a new record rather than updating the existing record.

This code updates the Address record correctly.  It does not add a new one:

```
using (CSIntUnitOfWork uow = new CSIntUnitOfWork())
{
    CustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(uow, _resellerID);

    DataModels.Customer updateCustomer = customerRepository.GetByID(customer.CustomerID);

    updateCustomer.ResellerID = customer.ResellerID;
    updateCustomer.CustomerType = customer.CustomerType;
    updateCustomer.Password = customer.Password;
    updateCustomer.Comments = customer.Comments;

    updateCustomer.Address.ResellerID = customer.Address.ResellerID;
    updateCustomer.Address.AddressCode = customer.Address.AddressCode;
    updateCustomer.Address.AddressType = customer.Address.AddressType;
    updateCustomer.Address.CompanyName = customer.Address.CompanyName;
    updateCustomer.Address.LastName = customer.Address.LastName;
    updateCustomer.Address.FirstName = customer.Address.FirstName;

    uow.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code will always add a new Address record:

```
using (CSIntUnitOfWork uow = new CSIntUnitOfWork())
{
    CustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(uow, _resellerID);

    DataModels.Customer updateCustomer = customerRepository.GetByID(customer.CustomerID);

    Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, Customer>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerID, opt => opt.Ignore());
    Mapper.Map(customer, updateCustomer);

    Mapper.CreateMap<Address, Address>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.Ignore());
    Mapper.Map(customer.Address, updateCustomer.Address);

    uow.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured it out.

AutoMapper is mapping ALL the fields in Customers, including the Address field.  The following code works great:

```
using (CSIntUnitOfWork uow = new CSIntUnitOfWork())
{
    CustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(uow, _resellerID);

    DataModels.Customer updateCustomer = customerRepository.GetByID(customer.CustomerID);

    Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, Customer>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerID, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.Ignore());  // <-- This was the problem!
    Mapper.Map(customer, updateCustomer);

    Mapper.CreateMap<Address, Address>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.Ignore());
    Mapper.Map(customer.Address, updateCustomer.Address);

    uow.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: AutoMapper map nested properties. Means you don't need to Map the Address seperatly. Just create a map for it before mapping the 'customer' and it will be mapped automatically.

Comment: How do I create a nested map?

Comment: AutoMapper supports it out of the box, just "CreateMap" for all the nested types before the mapping.

Comment: As Maxim points out.  You should just move your Mapper.CreateMap<> statement for Address above the Mapper.Map() call on Customer.